# Additional bytes received by a DatagramPacket

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I have a problem that I see for the first time ever, I'm using java DatagramSocket (s) for sending and receiving data in my app.

this is how I send the data:

```
byte[] buffer = "my data".getBytes();
senderPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 0, buffer.length, remoteAddress, remotePort);
socket.send(senderPacket);
```

now when I sent the byt[] buffer, it's size was 275.
but when I received the packet on the receiving app and got the byte[] from the receiverPacket, like this:

```
buffer = new byte[2048];
receiverPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(receiverPacket);
```

I found that the received bytes count where 278 bytes that's additional 3 bytes.

This might seem like not a big problem, but actually it is for me, please any idea why is this happening, and how to solve it, any logical explanation would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: Can you run a tool like tcpdump to see exactly what's going across the wire? It would be useful to know if these extra bytes are appearing at the sending or receiving end.

Comment: I don't see any code here that determines the length of the packet.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 extra bytes could be a length marker. I know that when I do sockets in C/C++, I typically dedicate the first 4 bytes to sending the length of my message, and then I use that data to determine how much to read in order to read the entire message.

Comment: It shouldn't be magically adding length markers (or anything else for that matter). 3 bytes would be a strange size for a length marker in any case, since UDP packets are limited to 65536 bytes so the length can be happily encoded in 2 bytes.